# ConnectionString Value Error

Tags: c#, sql, database, connection-string

I copied the ConnectString value from the properties of my local database.

Connection String from the properties is :

```
Data Source=Cyber\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GeneratedData;Integrated Security=True;
```

When I directly copy the ConnectionString into ConnectString, I get an error. So I take that "\" off and I did not get an error. However it still does not work. I also noticed that people usually change that ConnectionString value to a single word to make it easy.However, my VB properties section is not allowing me to change it. [Here is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nne7G.png)

```
public class SQLConnection
{
    #region MemberVariables
    private SqlConnection mConnection = null;
    private SqlDataAdapter mDataAdapter = null;
    private SqlCommand mCommand = null;
    static string mDbConnString = string.Empty;
    #endregion

    #region PublicMemberVariables
    public SqlConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return mConnection;
        }
        set
        {
            mConnection = value;
        }
    }
    public SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter
    {
        get
        {
            return mDataAdapter;
        }
        set
        {
            mDataAdapter = value;
        }
    }
    public SqlCommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return mCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            mCommand = value;
        }
    }
    public string ConnectString
    {
        get
        {
            return mDbConnString;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (mDbConnString)
            {
                mDbConnString = value;
            }
            lock (mConnection)
            {
                mConnection.ConnectionString = mDbConnString;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public void TestConnection()
    {
        ConnectString = "Data Source=Cyber SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GeneratedData;Integrated Security=True";
        Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectString);
        Connection.Open();
        MessageBox.Show(Connection.State.ToString());
    }


}
```

Comment: If you're thinking of using just one connection for all your database access, you're doing it wrong. The correct way is: open connection, do operation, close connnection, dispose connection.

Comment: DB "helper" classes like it looks like you are building are usually  more both than they are worth.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks. What I am trying to achieve is converting xml file into database. I am thinking of using one connection. But still learning and trying to build a strategy.

Comment: Also somebody answered the question and deleted their answer. If someone runs into the same problem for the future here is the answer:
Instead of "\" I had to have "\\".

Comment: @JackTheRipper "converting xml file into database" is a solved problem for many databases if you search for that phrase.

Comment: Named Pipe for Sql Server also activated ?

Comment: @Andrew Morton Thanks for your help. I am trying to find out how to do it with Bulk Insert. So far I have found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx

Comment: @JackTheRipper Please notice how your question does not relate to the actual problem. Perhaps you need to do some more research ;) [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Data Source=Cyber\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GeneratedData;Integrated Security=True;
```

To

```
Data Source=Cyber\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GeneratedData;Integrated Security=True;
```